# Should I report unrealistic deadlines assigned to me by other colleagues to my manager?

Tags: professionalism, management, startup, time-management

There is this person X, who would assign an unrealistic deadline and ask to build things that she won't use regularly. This has happened previously also and I had reported it to my manager and he handled it (a verbal argument happened between X and me). Things were okay between X and me post my manager talking.

4 days ago X again asked me to build something but said that she won't need it before 2 weeks. Now today she asked me to build it by EOD or not possible then by tomorrow first half. I don't have any issues building things but my problem is this unrealistic deadline and expectations.

Like 4 days back she was okay with me giving it after 2 weeks now she wants it tomorrow or by EOD.

Should I bring this up to my manager again and yes then how?

Comment: Does this colleague have the authority to set your work in the first place? Or is this part of your normal job description? Colleagues don't usually get to tell you what to do at all, but understanding how work normally gets distributed might help you get better answers.

Comment: Part of my normal JD. There will be requests coming from here.

Comment: I haven't told her my deadline yet because I am working on some other task with my manager so once I know what all his requirements are to be changed/added in the task post that only I can give her something. Also, I told my manager about it too he said just say no if its not possible and send a new deadline.Given that this has happened twice it looks like something which wont stop from her end.

Comment: Who normally manages your deadlines, and how far in advance are they? In the professional world, my manager has always been the one responsible for determining what my workload is and would have a fit if someone else decided to demand something get fit in ASAP.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should refer her to your manager. It's the managers job to be watching your workload and authorising things, especially if they're urgent. Really she should be going through your manager to get tasks assigned.

If you don't want to do that then just tell her the timeframe you think is reasonable. Either she accepts your timeframe or goes to the manager like she should with urgent stuff. Win win.

For routine tasks it doesn't matter, but anything urgent or involving a potential confrontation should have your manager in the loop from the outset.

Comment: My manager doesn't like that link of people coming to him and asking about me for work and then him referring. He just truncates the communication by asking everyone to come directly to me.

Comment: Don't do the managers job unless you're also collecting their pay.

Comment: Yeah I told her that neither today nor the first half of tomorrow is possible she asked me to give her a revised deadline.

Comment: great so whats the problem then?

Comment: It has happened twice now. Looks like a pattern to me.

Comment: ok it's a pattern, and you have a solution, stick with it.

Comment: in most cases, giving deadlines is your manager's job, not yours.

Answer (score 8):

> Like 4 days back she was okay with me giving it after 2 weeks now she
> wants it tomorrow or by EOD.

To this, I would have asked two questions:

> Why has the deadline changed?
>
> And/or why tomorrow before lunch at the latest?

The timeline is only part of the issue. To me, this is also a question of respect.

If she doesn't answer those two questions, or if her tone of voice makes it sound like you shouldn't be asking questions, then I would still do the work as quickly as possible (assuming I could shuffle my other work around), but then I'd have a serious talk with my manager afterward.

And to my manager, this is what I'd say:

> Four days ago, Karen told me she needed a widget built two weeks from then. I told her I could do that. Yesterday, she told me she needed that same widget built by the end of the day, or at the latest before lunch that following day.
>
> Now, I would have totally understood if Karen had started her request by saying:
>
> "I'm so sorry. I made a huge mistake in my original planning. Or my boss just changed his mind and now he wants to do a client demo tomorrow. [...]
>
> But is there any way you could get this widget built sooner?
>
> [...]
>
> By tomorrow if possible? Again, the demo time was changed and there are clients coming to visit us tomorrow afternoon.

In other words, I have a feeling this would have gone a lot better if she had said any of those things to you.

> Instead, she gave me a new deadline, didn't explain why the deadline was changed, or even why it needed to be done before tomorrow afternoon. [...]
>
> Now, I've already completed the work and told her the work was completed, because that's who I am, I like to do good work and I like to work quickly. But can you please speak to her? I don't want this to happen again.
>
> The way this was handled, I'm still not sure if the new deadline was actually serious, or completely arbitrary. Or if she didn't trust me to do the work by the original deadline or if she just handled the issue this way just to bully me. Either way, I need personal assurances that this kind of behavior doesn't happen again.

Comment: I said neither today nor tomorrow first half is possible to her. She asked me to give her a timeline.

Comment: @Notsure Then tell her when you will be able to do it. It seems that the manager trusts and expects you to manage your own time and workload as far as you can, thus implicitly giving you the power to decide when something will be done, according to your schedule and availability. If the timeline you provide others is not good enough for the others, they will need to talk to your manager since you would obviously need to drop other things and impact other deadlines to meet theirs. That part will then be on your manager to decide and manage.

Comment: @Notsure, I've just amended my answer.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Wow! She has never ever thanked me for the things I have built or even politely asked me.